# Could ediff-buffers re-use the current window configuration?

Tags: window, ediff

For instance, say that I have a two-window vertical split.  If I call
`ediff-buffers` from the right window, it will swap the right and the
left window for the diff, and even leave it like that afterwards.

I'd like `ediff` to try to keep the buffers in the same order during
the diff.  Is there already some setting that does this?

Comment: You might have to write a custom function, then tell ediff to use it by customizing `ediff-window-setup-function`

Comment: Yes, that's a given.  But maybe there's already some little-known `(require
'ediff-foobar)` that does this.  That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there were no replies so far, apparently there's no magical
solution.

Here's the solution I went with:

```
(apply #'ediff-regions-internal
           `(,@(if (equal (selected-window)
                          (lispy--vertical-splitp))
                   (append e1 e2)
                   (append e2 e1))
               nil ediff-regions-linewise nil nil))
```

A utility function that might be of use to others:

```
(defun lispy--vertical-splitp ()
  "Return nil if the frame isn't two vertical windows.
In case it is, return the left window."
  (let ((windows (window-list)))
    (when (= (length windows) 2)
      (let ((wnd1 (car windows))
            (wnd2 (cadr windows)))
        (when (= (window-pixel-top wnd1)
                 (window-pixel-top wnd2))
          (if (< (window-pixel-left wnd1)
                 (window-pixel-left wnd2))
              wnd1
            wnd2))))))
```